# Four finger swipe not working on Magic Trackpad

Tags: macos, magic-trackpad

Even though in the preference pane for Trackpad it says "Swipe between full-screen apps" when I'm using the internal trackpad in my laptop, it will switch desktops even if I'm not using full screen apps. However, when I'm using my Magic Trackpad, the 4-finger swipe does not switch desktops.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! You should post the solution below (click `Answer Your Question`), instead of posting it in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Solution: Go into settings -> trackpad -> turn off the four finger swipe, and turn it on again.

(Credit to Stiwi for the very efficient Jeopardy Question)

Comment: Please note: This may actually lock up your trackpad. The fix if this happens is to power off and on your trackpad and it should resync.